# What word is complimentary, but sounds like "chunky"?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

For a discussion I'm having with a colleague, we're trying to think of complimentary words that sound ugly.

Any that rhyme with chunky (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: So much, always, depends on context. Chunky might be great for a chocolate chip cookie, but uncomplimentary to a woman.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**pulchritude**

It sounds horrible (to me, at least) - but [means beauty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pulchritude) (see also: pulchritudinous).

As for complimentary words that sound rhyme with chunky: how about "funky"?

**EDIT:** [Definition of funky](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/funky).

Comment: That is one disgusting sounding word! Funky is a good idea!

Comment: I didn't realize "funky" was complimentary.

Comment: @MMyers Did you consider whether it is derogatory or not?

Comment: @Mark C: now that you mention it, a (rather old-fashioned) meaning of "funky" is "smelly", which is definitely not complimentary!

Comment: I had forgotten that one, although it is not "old-fashioned" to me.

Comment: It sounds horrible, because it leads to the portmanteau "sepulchritude", which might be coined for "beauty in death". If you Google for "sepulchritude", you will find that many have thought of this word already, so the phonetic association is more or less obvious.

Answer (score 5):

**[puissant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/puissant)**

It means *powerful, mighty, potent*, and sounds exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

**hunky**

I've always thought this was a stupid-sounding word, although young women seem enamored of it to describe their boyfriends.

For that matter, I can't think of much that's more pleasant or beautiful than a girl, but the word "girl", with its initial gutteral, consecutive liquids, and complete lack of a true vowel, is not among the most beautiful of words.

Answer (score 2):

[**Spunky**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spunky)

That was the first word that came to mind when I read the question.

Here are [results from a rhyming dictionar](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=chunky&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l)y:

> **One syllable:** clunky, funky, hunky, junkie, junky, monkey, punky, spunky
>
> (See the link for words with more syllables, like "grease monkey".)

My, this seems like the kind of site I could have spent a lot of time answering questions on!